# Websudo Phantom JDK8 can't see JdkLocalDateTime type

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am using

- `phantom-dsl_2.11` version 1.28.13.
- `phantom-jdk8_2.11` version
  1.28.13.

I have a simple:
User.scala

```
Case User (
  verifiedAt: Option[LocalDateTime]
)
```

UserDatabase.scala

```
import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._
import com.websudos.phantom.jdk8.dsl._

class UserModel extends CassandraTable[ConcreteUserModel, User]{
  object verifiedAt extends OptionalPrimitiveColumn[ConcreteUserModel, User, **JdkLocalDateTime**](this)
}
```

Issue is, I can't see `JdkLocalDateTime` and `OptionalJdkLocalDateTime` in scope even though I have imported jdk8 dsl.

However, `JdkLocalDate` and `OptionalJdkLocalDate` are in scope.

Appreciate any guidance.

[Phantom repo's package.scala](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/develop/phantom-jdk8/src/main/scala/com/websudos/phantom/jdk8/dsl/package.scala)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of phantom, that particular column was added less than 2 days ago, simply bump the version to 1.29.6 and all your troubles should be fixed :)